# Change label text on radio button selection with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the label text on a radio button when it is selected from "Set default" to "default" - How can this be done with jQuery? I presume that you would use the class `radio-default`as the selector but I don't know much about jQuery.

```html
<div class="radio-default">
  <input type="radio" id="line-radio-1" name="line-radio">
  <label for="line-radio-1">Set default</label>           
</div>

<div class="radio-default">
  <input type="radio" id="line-radio-2" name="line-radio">
  <label for="line-radio-2">Set default</label>           
</div>

<div class="radio-default">
  <input type="radio" id="line-radio-3" name="line-radio">
  <label for="line-radio-3">Set default</label>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("input[name='line-radio']").click(function() {
      $('.radio-default label').text('Set default');
      if(this.checked){
       $(this).next().text('default');
      }
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyf7bs2a/16/)

Comment: Why not $('.radio-default label').text('default'); ?

Comment: Is there a way to use this with font awesome icons? Here is the modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zyf7bs2a/17/

Answer (score 2):

Use below script

```
 $( "input:radio" ).click(function() {
    $(':radio').each(function() {
        $("#"+this.id).next().text( "Set default" );
    });

    $("#"+this.id).next().text( "Default" );

});
```

Comment: How can I make it change back after another radio has been selected? https://jsfiddle.net/zyf7bs2a/5/

Comment: @Simon welcome Simon, Please mark as correct and upvote too :)

Comment: I have accepted another response as it calls the radio by name.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:-

```
 var $radioButtons = $('.radio-default input:radio[name="line-radio"]');
 $radioButtons.change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'on'){
       $radioButtons.siblings('label').text('Set default');
       $(this).siblings('label').text('default')
    }
});
```

Working JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zyf7bs2a/10/)

Comment: How can I do this on click and when another radio is selected it changes back?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an on click hadler on the radio button

```
<input type="radio" id="line-radio-1" name="line-radio" onClick="yourFunc">

yourFunc: function(e){
    $(e).next('label').text('your text');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to reset the text on the previoused button clicked, but this can help you:

```
$('.radio-default').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('label').text("set");
})
```

Comment: Yes how can I reset the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
   $('label').text('Set default');
   $(this).next('label').html('Default');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ph2gvjcc/